# How can I set the max-width of a table row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to set max-width of a table-row. My CSS code:

```
table tr {
    max-width: 1580px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, padding is seen in the browser, but it doesn't push it. Margin and max-width are not even seen in the browser - inspect/computed.

Comment: Each table row is as wide as the table itself, so its width is either derived from the table or (if the tables width is not defined) by the width of the cells (i.e. *all*  cells in the table), and if those don't have defined widths, by their contents.

Comment: A table row has very specific and restrictive rules for rendering, because it has to be aligned with the other table rows and the column widths depend (in some cases) on the column contents. The bottom line is: use `padding` on cells (`<td>`s), not on the rows. You'll also have trouble using margin on both table rows and cells. If you want to control the position of the cell contents, the most predictable results are to wrap the cell contents in a `<div>` and apply margin/padding to that wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know there are a lot of properties you cannot use with tr element like border and max-width is one of them so you should rather try  giving it to td element.
And for  Properties that works with tr like background it does not apply to tr itself
it applies to all its children.
FOR EXAMPLE -

```css
tr{
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<table>
      <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

In the above code instead bg being applied to all of the row it applies to all children of the  element

Answer (score -1):

Try this out!

```
tr {
    max-width: 1580px;
    width:100%
}
```

Comment: I have tried, doesn't work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).